# How to add Jsoup in my project?

Tags: android

I want to parse a html file, and i found Jsoup in google

and i download Jsoup-1.6.3.jar

then i create a file in my project root named libs

in eclipse -> RIGHT_CLICK the project -> properties -> Libraries -> add jars

-> choose Jsoup.jar in folder libs -> ok

but when i click Jsoup.jar in Libraries, i found that:

Source attachment(None), Javadoc location(None), Native library location(None)

did i lose any step?

Can someone teach me how to import Jsoup in project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

1. Create a folder "libs"
2. Add your jar into libs folder
3. **Right click on jars and select Build Path -> Add to build path.**, it will create a "Referenced Library" folder in your project structure.

Comment: i followed your step but still not work, in Build path -> Libraries click jsoup.jar,  Source attachment, Javadoc location, and Native library location is alos none

Comment: Have you done "Add to build path"? Still if possible, show me your project structure.

Comment: Right click on Jar in Libs -> Select Build path -> Add to build path. Thats it

Comment: I already did the step you said, the link above is the result view after i add Jsoup to Build path, but it still not work :(

Comment: `Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();`

this is a part of code in my project, when my mouse move to "Jsoup", it appears messgae below:
Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.

Answer (score 1):

Copy or move your Jsoup-1.6.3.jar into your project source then right click on the Jsoup-1.6.3.jar, Build path and add to Build path. Done your're good to go!