# Getting "Source not found" error

Tags: java, jsoup

I have been trying to fix this problem for more then 3 hours. I have noticed that there are question with similar problem and i have tried everything but its still not working.

I think that the problem has something to do with JSoup JAR file.
Here is link to similar problem [How to add Jsoup in my project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857281/how-to-add-jsoup-in-my-project)

I have tried to set up both Android and normal Java project and same error appears.

EDIT: Here is the code, just in case

```
    import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
    import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
    import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

    public class Klasa {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            String servisURL = "http://www.sczg.unizg.hr/student-servis/";
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(servisURL).get();
            Elements jobNode = doc.select("div.jobBox");
            System.console().writer().print(jobNode.get(0).text());
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage().toString());
                }
            }
     }
```

EDIT2: I have solved the problem

Just change `System.console().writer().print(jobNode.get(0).text());`

to

`System.out.print(jobNode.get(0).text());`

Comment: Is it an error, or information? Did you attach any source to the jar?

Comment: I imagine this error is showing in your IDE in which you have set up your project? Are you using Eclipse by any chance?

Comment: @DaveNewton I have downloaded jar from here http://jsoup.org/download I have tried to add "jsoup-1.7.2-sources.jar optional sources jar" from that site and it still didnt work
Also, i have tried to add "jsoup-1.7.2-javadoc.jar optional javadoc jar" from that site and it still didnt work

Comment: @Jubbat I am using Eclipse. When debugging im getting "Source not found." error in new tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse, then follow these steps,

1. Right click on your project.
2. Go to Properties -> Java Build Path
3. Click on the Source tab -> Add Folder button.
4. Add the source folder of your project.
5. In case you want to attach an external source like a jar, click on Link Source.

Comment: You said you get issues while debugging. Does that mean your code is compiling successfully? Are you facing issues when doing "Right click on code and hitting Debug"?

Comment: Debugger starts and when i get after the breakpoint i get "Source not found." error in new tab. Name of that tab is "Thred.exit()line:not available[local variables unavailable]"

Comment: maybe the debug flag was turned off when compiling jsoup jar. What you can do is create another project with the source code of JSoup. Set debug on the newly created JSoup Project. Then run the code from your project.

Comment: you can also try attaching the source of JSoup this way, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523955/how-can-i-bind-sources-of-3rd-party-jar-to-eclipse-for-debugging-when-jar-is-not. Just ctrl+click on the JSoup API that you use in your code and it'll give you the bytecode instruction set of JSoup. Then click on the Attach Source button.

Comment: Im an idiot...same thing happens when i try to debug simple output to console. That means something is wrong in my code from post. The code runs but nothing goes to console